# How can I upload current UTC time to Parse date column?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload the current UTC time to a date "field" in Parse. How can I do this?

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("utc"));
String utcTime = df.format(new Date());

message.put("lastReplyUpdatedAt", utcTime);
message.saveInBackground();
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the right imports to work for the classes above so I can't construct my String. What can I do here? Also I'm not sure if Parse would even accept that String. Are there any special formats I need to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pass a `Date`

From the [Parse platform documentation](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/), pass a `Date` object rather than a String.

```
Date myDate = new Date();
message.put("lastReplyUpdatedAt", myDate);
message.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Perfectly acceptable to post an Answer to your own question, even encouraged. No need to explain doing so.

Comment: Lol not sure if that was sarcastic, but yeah I found the answer fairly quickly after posting the question. I figure it will help someone else and I couldn't find a duplicate here on SO, at least worded in the way that I think people who want this answer would word it.

Comment: @bluemunch Not sarcastic at all. Self answering _is_ encouraged. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Cheers! Didn't know that.